# How can I compare two audio files and get rid of the data which exists in both?

Tags: audio, compare, editing

I'll start with an example.

"You have two audio files (same codec and file-extension). File A contains a sound which is mixed with background music, and File B contains nothing but that same background music. If you had to remove the background music from File A by comparing it to File B and getting rid of the common audio, how would you do it?"

This is the problem. I've been searching the internet for hours, looking for a way to accomplish this, yet all I found was sites about "removing duplicate files". So, is this even theoretically possible and how could it be done? If it's not possible, what would you recommend me to do to get rid of the background music from File A without affecting the other sound's quality (much)?

Answer (score 0):

If the mix in File A is just a linear superposition of File B and another sound – you could just find the exact volume of the background (File B) and subtract it from File A.

If it's natural mix (e.g. a microphone recording the scene) it is a much more involved problem. Then this question definetly belongs to [dsp.stackexchange](http://dsp.stackexchange.com) and probably needs some source separation techniques to be solved.

Comment: Assuming it's the former, how should I substract it? I'm unaware if that can be done with Audacity (or any other free software, because I don't have Adobe Audition or the like).

Comment: If you want to use Audacity, you can invert File B and mix it with File A. If you want to do it programmatically, it is just samplewise substraction.